# Aer Estimator in qiskit related question in a noisy backend

Tags: python, qiskit

In case when we will use noise model from a fake backend in aer estimator, in that case whether we can use approximation=True and a fixed seed value? And please give details what they (approximation and seed) exactly do in aer estimator

I am using aer estimator in qiskit to estimate energy importing noise from a fake backend. I am confused whether I can use approximation=True and a fixed seed in that case

```
from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator as AerEstimator

noisy_estimator = AerEstimator(
    backend_options={
        "method": "statevector",
        "coupling_map": coupling_map,
        "noise_model": noise_model,
    "basis_gates": basis_gates},
    run_options={"seed": seed,"shots": 10000},
     transpile_options={"seed_transpiler": seed},
     approximation=True
)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I think your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)